# in windows forms controls in tabpage increments by one when tabpage is recreated

Tags: c#, winforms

In my windows form I create a tabpage and added controls to them. But when I close a particular tabpage and reopen it then the controls in it are incremented by one.

I mean to say, I only want to display one panelbox in tabpage when I close it and reopen it. the tabpage contains two panels.

Here is the code:

```
//onButtonClickEvent
TabPage tab1 = new TabPage();
tab1.Name = "CriminalRecord";
tab1.Text = "Criminal Record".ToString();
tab1.Visible = true;
tab1.BackColor = Color.Brown;

if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count != 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
    {
        if (tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(tab1))
        {
            tabControl1.SelectTab(tab1);
        }
        else
        {
            tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab1);
            tab1.Controls.Add(loadPanelBottom());
            tab1.Controls.Add(loadPanel());
            tab1.Controls.Add(loadPanelTop());
        }
    }
}
else
{
    tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab1);
    tab1.Controls.Add(loadPanelBottom());
    tab1.Controls.Add(loadPanel());
    tab1.Controls.Add(loadPanelTop());
}

Splitter loadPanel()
{
    Splitter splitter1 = new Splitter();
    splitter1.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
    splitter1.Cursor = Cursors.HSplit;
    splitter1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    splitter1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    splitter1.Name = "splitter1";
    splitter1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 5);
    splitter1.TabIndex = 1;

    return splitter1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare new tabpage into the form class
example

```
public partial class main:form
{
    TabPage tab1;
}
```

and then

```
//onButtonClickEvent
TabPage tab1 = new TabPage();
tab1.Name = "CriminalRecord";
tab1.Text = "Criminal Record".ToString();
tab1.Visible = true;
tab1.BackColor = Color.Brown;
```